# The input string was not in the correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, asp.net-mvc-4, int

i'm getting an error in this piece of code with asp.net mvc 4 "input string was not in a correct format" i know why i get this error because im making a search filter by Marca (Brand, im making it in spanish), the dropdownlist where the brands are in a table are in string value, but the row in the Items Table where they are related is an int value. The search results http post tries to do it with string values and i get the error, if i type manually in the url the int id of the brand i want to search the query passes. Here is an example of my code and sorry for my bad english.

```
public ActionResult Index(string marcas, string search_query)
    {
var MarcaLst = new List<string>();

var MarcaQry = from d in db.Marcas // table Brand
               orderby d.Marca1 // string row of the table Brand
               select d.Marca1;
MarcaLst.AddRange(MarcaQry.Distinct());
ViewBag.marcas = new SelectList(MarcaLst);

var marca = from m in db.Marcas
            select m;

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search_query))
{
    descripcion = descripcion.Where(s => s.Descripcion.ToUpper().Contains(search_query.ToUpper()));
}

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(marcas))
    return View(descripcion.ToList());
else
{
    int marcasint = Convert.ToInt32(marcas); // I get the error here from a work around to make the page load
    return View(descripcion.Where(x => x.MarcaID == marcasint)); //MarcaID is the int value of the Items table for the Brand
}
}
```

> > url/articulos?search_query=a&marcas=BSN //Error
> >
> > url/articulos?search_query=a&marcas=1 //Pass

Comment: Are you sure that marcas is correctly bound to the action parameter ? (might need to include whole action code, as well as corresponding view, and perhaps view-model)

Comment: How did you read the value of variable "marcas"? You didn't show it in your code... / ¿Cómo lees el valor de la variable "marcas"? No lo mostraste en el código que pusiste...

Comment: Side note: please avoid shrtng varbl nams - there is no value in saving 1 character (unless your goal is to make code unreadable) - "Lst" or "Qry" are very hard to read. Also try to stay consistent with naming of local variables - you have camelCase, UpperCase, underscore-separated, and even all-lower-case identifiers in your small sample.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to convert string to integer.So the string must be in the right format.For example, You cannot convert "abc1" to integer. You can use `Int32.TryParse(stringVal)` to check for possiblity of type conversion and convert. The above method returns boolean.

Answer (score 2):

Don't just throw in a string to Convert and assume it's a valid integer if it's not null or empty. Use TryParse instead:

```
int marcasint;
bool success = Int32.TryParse(marcas, out marcasint);
if (success){
    return View(descripcion.Where(x => x.MarcaID == marcasint));
} else {
    return View(descripcion.ToList());
}
```

Comment: Doing this method and now i get an error with the controller saying that not all code paths return a value. Error 1 'DBFEF5.Controllers.articulosController.Index(string, string)': not all code paths return a value

Comment: @Maxcancer Well I thought you'd figure the rest out yourself. Well, I added some more details to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

try the Int32.TryParse method to try to convert the string to a integer. All major number formats have the TryParse methods:

Documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try using `TryParse` method

```
 int marcasint;
 if(Int32.TryParse(marcas, out marcasint))
 {
    return View(descripcion.Where(x => x.MarcaID == marcasint));
 }
 else
 {
    //change eles part as required.
    return View(descripcion.Where(x => x.MarcaID == -1));
 }
```

After reading your comments, I think you don't need to filter records by `MarcaID` but it's name. So try this and replace `BrandName` with correct field name.

```
 return View(descripcion.Where(x => x.BrandName == marcas));
```

Comment: Doing this method and now i get an error with the controller saying that not all code paths return a value. Error 1 'DBFEF5.Controllers.articulosController.Index(string, string)': not all code paths return a value

Comment: You need to return something (with same type) on the else part... I left a comment as I wasn't sure what to return. pls check my updated answer.

Comment: good thing is that it doesnt throw error, bad thing is that the search  still doesnt work

Comment: what do you want `search by` if `marcas is not an int`?

Comment: the code is suppose to work using the Brands name as a filter in a dropdownlist, the Brands table has two row, and int (MarcaID) acting as a PK and a string (Marca) with has the name of the brand, in the table Items i have the MarcaID row with a FK to the Brand table. The code successfully gets the Dropdownlist with the brands, but when i try to search something using the filter with any brands it gets the error because the value entered in the action to compare with the Items.MarcaID is a string and not an int

Comment: It doesn't matter if the string is convertible to an int (ex; "123"). Error is when it is not convertible (ex; "ABC").

Comment: exactly, and none are convertible since they are brands names like BSN, GAESCA, etc